# How to set not just tag name/key and also value in this PowerShell script?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

```
$res = Get-AzResource -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$res.ForEach{
    if ( $_.tags.ContainsKey('sada') ) {
        $_.tags.Remove('sada')
    }
    $_ | Set-AzResource -Tags $_.tags
}
```

I have used this code but i want to set not just tag name/key and also value.
How I can do that? Thanks)

Answer (score 0):

depending on if tag already exists you need to assign value to it or create it:

```
if ( $_.tags.ContainsKey('yournewkey') ) {
    $_.tags.yournewkey = 'some_value'
} else {
    $_.tags.Add('yournewkey', 'some_value' )
}
```

basically, its just a hashtable, you can read more on hashtables here: https://powershellexplained.com/2016-11-06-powershell-hashtable-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about/

Comment: but how to remove tags with specific value using Powershell ?

`$res = Get-AzResource -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$res.ForEach{
    if ( $_.tags.ContainsKey('sada') ) {
        $_.tags.Remove('sada')
    }
    $_ | Set-AzResource -Tags $_.tags
}`

Comment: check tag value with if statement, for example